# Overridding View for Different Platforms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a multiplatform app set up, so far it is working decently. My main issue though is I need to change the layout between IOS and Android. In my main solution I have a class called LocationView:

```
class LocationView : ContentView {
    LocationView() {
        InitializeView();
    }
}
```

...and it's subsequent XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="Cabs.Views.LocationPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Label Text="I'm regular with a bunch of regular stuff" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

For IOS, I need to change  and subsequent controls (UIcontrols based, etc)

What is the correct way of doing this?

I know it has something to do w/ DI, not sure of the syntax. I tried the following:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LocationPage))]
```

It still isn't working

```
I try calling  await Navigation.PushAsync(new DependencyService.Get<LocationPage>())
```

But I get a compile error

What is the correct procedure for this?

Thanks

Comment: That ContentPage's XAML will automatically render your `Label` as a `UILabel` on iOS, so all you have to do is `await Navigation.PushAsync(new LocationPage());`

Comment: Tried that, it's still rendering the original page. I have the original page in the main solution, then I have an IOS specific one in the IOS solution

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do then. Are you looking for embedding native controls? Or custom renderers? Or ? https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/ / https://xamarinhelp.com/basics-xamarin-forms-custom-renderers/

Comment: To be specific: I want to implement a map control using the native functionality of each platform

Comment: Ah... Xamarin has examples of custom Map renderers and how they work : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/index